Why would a control flow block need access to the labels associated with a higher or lower level nested control flow block?
In Engineering a Compiler (Cooper, Torczon) 3rd Edition, Chapter 5 Syntax-Driven Translation, Section 5.3.3 Translating Control-Flow Statements, the following nested control-flow grammar is presented,
Stmt  --> if Expr then Stmt
    | if Expr then WithElse else Stmt
    | Other
WithElse --> if Expr then WithElse else WithElse
       | Other

The goal is to generate three-address IR code using syntax-driven translation actions. This involves the generation of branch and jump instructions, as well as target labels for each.
Then the author writes:
"The compiler writer must account for nested constructs. The three labels must
be stored in a way that both ties them to this specific instance of a WithElse
and makes them accessible to the other actions associated with rule 4. Our notation,
so far, does not provide a solution to this problem. The bison parser generator
extended yacc notation to solve it, so that the compiler writer does not need to
introduce an explicit stack of label-valued triples.

Why would a control flow block need access to the labels associated with a higher or lower level nested control flow block? I am confused why this information needs to be bound to the production rule.
